# Popup UIPickerview for swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wondering if anyone knows a Popup UIPickerView Control that looks like this exactly..

[image]

But instead of date picker I want it to be a Normal Picker. I have searched Cocoapods and Github and I always get Date pickers. And when I found a Popup Picker it was using Swift 1 and it was not updated.

So There must be something. I dont think that iOS users always have to implement the popup by them selfs everytime they need one for a view.

Please note that I am asking for this control for Swift 3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736826/uitextfield-with-pickerview-as-firstresponder-ios/40736909#40736909

Comment: What's the problem? A view is a view. Adding a view in code to your interface is easy. If you want a picker to appear, just make a picker and make it appear. If you want to get fancy, make it a presented view controller's view, but no law says you have to do so.

Comment: @matt.The people who built this for example: https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift Have built it to make the life of developers easier. I know how to do it by myself very well, What I am asking if there is a ready made control to use instead of re-inventing a very repetitive wheel. Thank you for your support

Comment: @SubhajitHalder Thank you

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat welcome please check some time for the Readme file update

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can create yourself.
Use a normal picker embedded in a classic UIView (with round corner) and bottom of this view you can add 2 button (cancel, done) and a label for the title.

In any case always try to consider the user experience not exactly the best...

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I have done. But when I finished I thought that there should be someone who just uploaded a control like that. Anyways Thank you :)